# Digital Ocean Capistrano Rails deployment wont display css/javascript

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unicorn, capistrano3, digital-ocean

I am trying to display a site on digital ocean under `http://104.131.13.122/`.  I have deployed it under capistrano using Unicorn.  This is my first deployment.  If you go to the site, no CSS/javascript is showing and if you try to view the js/css under view source.  It says it can not find it.  Obviously, locally Everything looks fine and I have no problem.  You can view all the code here: https://github.com/RubyQuarry/blog_alex  .  All I want is for the styling to now work.

This is my deploy.rb

```
# config valid only for Capistrano 3.1
lock '3.2.1'

set :application, 'appleJuiceScholars'
set :repo_url, 'git@github.com:/RubyQuarry/blog_alex.git'
set :rvm_ruby_version, '2.0.0'
set :stage, :production

# Default branch is :master
# ask :branch, proc { `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`.chomp }.call

# Default deploy_to directory is /var/www/my_app
# set :deploy_to, '/var/www/my_app'

# Default value for :scm is :git
# set :scm, :git

# Default value for :format is :pretty
# set :format, :pretty

# Default value for :log_level is :debug
# set :log_level, :debug

# Default value for :pty is false
# set :pty, true

# Default value for :linked_files is []
# set :linked_files, %w{config/database.yml}

# Default value for linked_dirs is []
# set :linked_dirs, %w{bin log tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/sockets vendor/bundle public/system}

# Default value for default_env is {}
# set :default_env, { path: "/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH" }

# Default value for keep_releases is 5
# set :keep_releases, 5

namespace :deploy do

  desc 'Restart application'
  task :restart do
    on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
      # Your restart mechanism here, for example:
      # execute :touch, release_path.join('tmp/restart.txt')
      invoke 'unicorn:restart'
    end
  end

  after :publishing, :restart

  after :restart, :clear_cache do
    on roles(:web), in: :groups, limit: 3, wait: 10 do
      # Here we can do anything such as:
      # within release_path do
      #   execute :rake, 'cache:clear'
      # end
    end
  end

end
```

This is my unicorn/production.rb

```
worker_processes 4
user "root"
working_directory "/var/www/appleJuiceScholars/current" # available in 0.94.0+

listen "/tmp/.sock", :backlog => 64
listen 80, :tcp_nopush => true

timeout 30

# feel free to point this anywhere accessible on the filesystem
pid "/var/unicorn.pid"

stderr_path "/var/unicorn.stderr.log"
stdout_path "/var/unicorn.stdout.log"

# combine REE with "preload_app true" for memory savings
# http://rubyenterpriseedition.com/faq.html#adapt_apps_for_cow
preload_app true
GC.respond_to?(:copy_on_write_friendly=) and
  GC.copy_on_write_friendly = true

before_fork do |server, worker|
  # the following is highly recomended for Rails + "preload_app true"
  # as there's no need for the master process to hold a connection
  #defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and
  #  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect!

  old_pid = "#{server.config[:pid]}.oldbin"
  if old_pid != server.pid
    begin
      sig = (worker.nr + 1) >= server.worker_processes ? :QUIT : :TTOU
      Process.kill(sig, File.read(old_pid).to_i)
    rescue Errno::ENOENT, Errno::ESRCH
    end
  end
end

after_fork do |server, worker|
  # the following is *required* for Rails + "preload_app true",
  #defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and
  #  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
end
```

Gem file

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.1.6'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'

gem 'jquery-ui-rails'


# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc

# Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
gem 'spring',        group: :development

gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby

gem "figaro"


# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]

gem 'normalize-rails'

gem 'haml-rails'

gem 'font-awesome-rails' # for using font-awesome icons


group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'binding_of_caller'
  gem 'meta_request'
  gem 'guard-rspec'
  gem 'guard-livereload', require: false
end

group :development do
  gem 'capistrano-rails', '~> 1.1'
  gem 'capistrano3-unicorn'
end

group :production do
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
  gem 'unicorn'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes

end
```

Comment: Are you using any gems that modify asset URLs such as `asset_sync`?

Comment: ill post my gem list

Comment: can you write the nginx conf